# Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to boolean

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting a weird problem in Eclipse. I'm trying to set a boolean to null, but I am getting an error.

[image: Boolean to Null]

How can I fix this and why is this happening?

Comment: You can't do that. Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: null is not a boolean value. use the  boxed Boolean class. I suspect this is java 101

Comment: Java is not C.  You can't assign `null` to a scalar variable.

Comment: The question is an XY problem. Folks, please don't suggest he use Boolean.

Comment: _"How can I fix this and why is this happening?"_ seriously? The tooltip answered both of your question perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Boolean and boolean are 2 different things. You should try Boolean (capital B)

boolean values can be either `true` or `false`

Boolean values can be either `true`, `false` or `null`.

Comment: And would require that all boolean tests be preceded by an if-null block. Just don't recommend use of Boolean here. The OP is obviously asking an XY problem, and will be much better served if he avoids use of the wrapper class inappropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types such as `boolean` can't be set to `null`.  Set the `boolean` to `true` or `false`.

Comment: What about if a method that is supposed to return a boolean returns `null`?

Comment: @Imray A method with a `boolean` return type attempting to `return null;` would not compile.

Comment: @Imray: a boolean method should **only** return true or false or **throw an exception**. Period.

Comment: @Imray Do you expect `null` to be a legitimate value?  If so, then use the wrapper class `Boolean` (capitalized).  You can't return `null` if the method returns a `boolean`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: However, if it is the `Boolean` type (note the capital b), can't it return null then?

Comment: @Pokechu22 In that case, it can.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what others are suggesting, **don't** use Boolean here. If you have a boolean method, it should return only true or false, or failing that, throw an exception. Otherwise you will be writing very fragile code, code that others or your future self might easily misuse.

In your code, what is supposed to happen when this occurs?

```
if (null) {
   // do something
}
```

It just doesn't make sense. Use boolean, set it to true or false, don't use Boolean. If you absolutely need a 3-valued type, then create an enum for this:

```
public enum ThreeStates {
  TRUE, FALSE, UNSURE
}
```

Comment: Also, if you use a `Boolean` of null and try to cast it to a `boolean`, you get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use Boolean, or set your boolean to a default value (true or false). You can't set primitives to NULL (boolean, int, long, etc).